# Maximum Weighted Path in a Weighted Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

The modification of Dijkstra Algorithm related to maximum weighted path in a weighted undirected graph is given here. 
[Finding path with maximum minimum capacity in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552964/finding-path-with-maximum-minimum-capacity-in-graph)
Can anyone give a clear and easy explanation of this algorithm by some example?

Comment: What is it specifically you don't understand from reading the link you posted or other articles you've found when googling?

Comment: The implementation of this pseudo code. I tried to apply to examples but couldn't reach the maximum weighted path.

Comment: My problem is to find maximum distance between any two nodes in a weighted undirected graph.